# Is it possible to get recurrence through alternating forward and backward propagation?

Tags: backpropagation, stochastic-gradient-descent

This is a purely theoretical question, and I'm not trying to solve some real world problem with this, and I don't care about how ineffective this may be, as long as it is theoretically possible.

For a simple NN trained with SGD, is it possible to find an initial configuration of weights, that won't converge (suck in local minima), which "abuses" back propagation to store state between each forward and backward pass pairs?

Say I have a NN with few fully connected layers and two input nodes and one output node.
This NN is now trained on "predicting" the first input using basic SGD with a fixed learning rate.
This is obviously very simple, but only in the example to make sure the NN can know the target trained for with sgd.

Is there an initial weight configuration that results in the network always outputting the second input used in the previous forward/backward pass?

Essentially:

```
nn: 2 x ... x 1 initialized with a certain state
input: float[2]
loop {
    last = input[1]
    input = randomize with -1 or 1
    target = input[0]
    nn.forward(input)
    nn.backward(nn.loss(target))
    assert nn.output[0] < 0 == last < 0
}
```

My intuition tells me, that it should be possible to have the weights direct the effect of the specific weights that toggle to the input, when the target output is "known" to it.

Maybe I'm mistaken, and you can actually show that it isn't possible for weights to direct the impact of back propagation in this way.

I've tried brute forcing the weight of smaller NNs, but didn't have success so far, so if it's possible I suspect it to not be very simple.